# How to use react-horizontal-timeline module in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, npm-package

I am working on react typescript project now.

This is my code snippet.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import HorizontalTimeline from 'react-horizontal-timeline';

interface Props {}

interface State {
  value: number;
  previous: number;
}

const VALUES: string[] = [
  '2008-06-01',
  '2010-06-01',
  '2013-06-01',
  '2015-03-01',
  '2019-01-01',
  '2019-06-17',
  '2019-08-01',
];

const Timeline: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<State>({ value: 0, previous: 0 });

  const handleIndexClick = (index: number) => {
    setState({ value: index, previous: state.value });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Bounding box for the Timeline */}
      <div style={{ width: '60%', height: '100px', margin: '0 auto' }}>
        <HorizontalTimeline
          index={state.value}
          indexClick={handleIndexClick}
          values={VALUES}
        />
      </div>
      <div className='text-center'>
        {/* any arbitrary component can go here */}
        {state.value}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Timeline;
```

I run this but I got error,
[image]

I tried to install @types/react-horizontal-timeline but I got this error.[image]

How can i fix this error?

Comment: It literally says in the error message, you need to make a declaration file (.d.ts) and [declare the module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules)

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: It tells you in the error message exactly what to do, additionally the documentation I linked has an anchor directly to the relevant code for the declaration file. If you still have a question about how to make a declaration file, search for it first and if you still can't find an answer, [write a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Should I custom node module?